# SQL Access COUNT in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to execute a query to return orders where they only have 1 cross reference number.

Something like this (field names and tables changed to protect the innocent ;-P) :

```
SELECT ordernum FROM orders WHERE (COUNT(orderref) = 1) ORDER BY ordernum;
```

The problem is, having an aggregate function is not possible in the WHERE clause using Access (not sure if it's allowed in normal SQL).

How can I achieve this using Access SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The count(*) has to be in the HAVING clause since it is calculated.  Also, you are missing a GROUP BY clause.

```
-- Updated statement
SELECT ordernum, COUNT(orderref) as Total
FROM orders 
GROUP BY ordernum 
HAVING COUNT(orderref) = 1 
ORDER BY ordernum
```

Someone emailed me stating that MS Access does not support the HAVING clause.  That is news to me.  A long time ago I was MOS ACCESS certified.

Let's use the Northwind database for MS Access 2007.  I change the syntax since the column names are different.  However, results are the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is working in Access but try something like this

```
SELECT ordernum FROM orders group by orderref having count(*) = 1 ORDER BY ordernum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SQL query:

```
SELECT ordernum,count(ordernum) as countorders FROM orders
GROUP BY ordernum
HAVING countorders = 1
ORDER BY ordernum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
 SELECT ordernum, count(orderref) 
 FROM    orders 
 ORDER BY ordernum, having count(orderref)=1;
```